# Create an index to speed up query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I took a SQL assessment test this week. And this question in specific is one I did not understand since I am not familiar with clustered, non-clustered indexes yet.

The SQL server table below is used to manage a company’s product purchases. The table contains 17 million rows. Which of the following SQL statements can be used to create an index such to calculate the total purchases for a given data will run the **shortest amount of time**?

```
CREATE TABLE [Production].[TransactionHistory]
(
    [TransactionID][int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [ProductionID][int] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionType][nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity][int] NOT NULL,
    [ActualCost][money] NOT NULL,
    [ProductionDate][dateTime] NOT NULL,
)
```

Which of the following queries can return data in the shortest amount of processing time? This will give me a good understanding of how indexes work. And there can be **up to 3 valid answers** in this question. Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help.

Option 1

```
CREATE COVERING INDEX IX_TranHistory_Covered 
  ON [Production].[TransactionHistory]
    (
        [ProductionDate] ASC,
        [ActualCost] ASC,
        [Quantity] ASC
    );
```

Option 2

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TranHistory_Covered 
   ON [Production].[TransactionHistory]
      (
        [ActualCost] ASC,
        [ProductionDate] ASC,
        [Quantity] ASC
      );
```

Option 3

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TranHistory_Covered 
   ON [Production].[TransactionHistory]
    (
        [Quantity]
    )
    INCLUDE
    (
        [ProductionDate],
        [ActualCost]
    );
```

Option 4

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TranHistory_Covered 
  ON [Production].[TransactionHistory]
    (
        [ProductionDate]
    )
    INCLUDE
    (
        [ActualCost] ASC,
        [Quantity] ASC
    );
```

Last option

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TranHistory_Covered 
    ON [Production].[TransactionHistory]
    (
        [ActualCost] ASC,
        [Quantity] ASC,
        [ProductionDate] ASC
    );
```

Comment: Homework? Enjoy...:)

Comment: Option 1: no such syntax as `COVERING`, and if option 4 looks perfect except it is invalid syntax, then option 4 is incorrect - it's a trick to make you pick the most likely one. Unless the exam writer messed up, which is unfortunately quite likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want option 4. The key (Production Date) will induce index seeks and by creating a covered index the information needed to do satisfy query is right there in the index tree and SQL Server does not have to retrieve the entire row to calculate the result. You don't want 'asc' in the include part of the index.